# Why can't I mount my network drive? (CentOS7)

Tags: centos, networking

Not sure how mount works with CentOS, but I have a drive accessed through my CentOS file explorer at the path:

```
smb://ipaddress/sharedfoldername
```

And want to permanently mount it to my PC at /mnt/ or at /home/user/desktop but the following commands are probably wrong but could someone tell me how to get the machine to connect to the address and mount it to the place I want it on startup/login?

These commands are probably wrong but it's just what I assumed would do the trick:

```
sudo mount smb:/ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mnt/
```

Obviously replacing `ipaddress` with my actual IP ADDRESS and replacing `sharedfoldername` with my real shared drive name. - But.... it doesn't work - it tells me that smb doesn't work...?... and also says I may have got the mount command wrong too because it brings up mount help...?

It is accessable from CentOS if I access the path `smb://ipaddress/sharedfoldername` but I would like it mounted to a specific folder...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

---

**SUBQUESTION**

Why is `_netfs` not recognised if you look at the command for fstab in @jsbillings comment?

Comment: See additional subquestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smb:// URL indicator is just for the file browser, it's not an actual mount path you can use with `mount`.

Try using something like this:

```
mount -t cifs //ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mnt --verbose -o user=username
```

A cifs mount would probably be best if you used a credentials file rather than hard-code a username and password into /etc/fstab -- a file readable by all users on the system.  You'd add a line something like this(one long line):

```
//ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mnt cifs credentials=/etc/smbcredentials,uid=1001,gid=1001,_netdev 0 0
```

And then create a file called /etc/smbcredentials that has this in it:

```
username=msusername
password=mspassword
```

(each on their own line)

Comment: You're really helping me out today! - Thanks, I'll have a go.

Comment: `sudo mount -t cifs //ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mnt --verbose -o user=(username),pass=(password)` worked. Just wondering if you know how to mount to the desktop etc. I tried the same commadn but changing /mnt/ to /home/username/Desktop but It didn't seem to do anything. I also realise the command doesn't mount permanently but I have set it to run on startup. Thanks

Comment: If I try to mount to Desktop/Documents etc. it says I have mounted it but nothing appears in those folders.....?

Comment: @ORICKETTS you probably want to also add uid and gid to the mout options. If you want it to mount on boot, you need to add it to /etc/fstab (using the correct syntax)

Comment: Again, @jsbillings I sound completely useless at this! - How could I add it on startup? - what line would I need to add to `/etc/fstab`? - What I was going to do is use the command `mate-session-properties` and add it to startup on there? - also how can I sort the mount to desktop/documents etc. thing out? - if you know what I should use - please could you specify the exact line of code that could solve both problems (startup and mount to user directories) - Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer with the fstab entry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that will come in useful but how can I get it to mount on startup like you mentioned (exact line of code if you know) and why it won't mount to desktop/docs etc. - Thanks

Comment: The addition you have made to the post worked well - thanks so much for that, that's sorted a security problem - but do you know anything about the questions in my comment earlier and I'll add them to the question too.

Comment: Question updated with subquestions below the question.

Comment: I've managed to get it to run on startup! - Finally! - Anyway - do you know why it wouldn't let me mount to a user directory like `/home/username/Desktop` or `/home/username/Documents`? Thanks

Comment: It probably would be better to mount it to a central location and create symlinks in your homedir to Desktop and Documents.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @jsbillings

Comment: I've hit a bump in the road - all was going well then I have come across a permissions problem - before I've been using root to test this out, but actually I need it to be mounted for a standard user. I have a script that I've set to run on startup with `mate-session-properties` which works for root, the script it just a plain executable .txt file with the command inside, but could I run it as root from that txt. script doc? - I'll explain more in the bottom of my question for you @jsbillings - please could you get back to me. Thanks

Comment: See updated question with urgent subquestions - thanks so much

Comment: Don’t mount it in a script. Put it in the fstab like in my answer. You’ll want to have the uid= and gid= parts refer to your user’s UID and GID. (See the output of `id -u` and `id -g`)

Comment: I seem to remember this not working when I tried it but I will exactly copy and paste your code into my `/etc/fstab/` file and change the info I need to and let you know the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: It says the mount option `_netfs` is not recognised. - Can you help?

Comment: Why is `_netfs` not recognised - I really need to sort this thanks :) **@jsbillings**

Comment: HI @jsbillings - the command `_netfs` is not being recognised - if you don't know why and can't sort it, do you know how to run su in a script? Thanks

Comment: Sorry try _netdev instead. Got it mixed up in my head.

Comment: No problem at all - I'll have a go :)

Comment: I get 'Unable to mount sharedfoldername, only root can mount sharedfoldername to sharedfoldermountlocation'

Comment: Yes this is something that only root can do. But it should be set up to automatically mount on boot

Comment: No - I get an error message that flashes up really quickly on startup, saying something like 'cifs mount failure'

Comment: Right - is there something I could edit the temporary mount command with (`sudo mount -t cifs //ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mountlocation --verbose -o credentials=credentialsfilelocation`) with to make it mount for a standard user but the sudo command executed by root because I could run that on startup. Also please see this question - I need your help! [CLICK HERE FOR LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590683/how-can-i-run-su-root-and-enter-credentials-in-a-script)

Comment: You’d be better off getting the mount to work than writing a script to mount it.

Comment: Thanks - but because I'm quite inexperienced with this I'm not sure how to correct it. It just doesn't mount and I get the error I put on startup as well. I can try to confirm the error in a minute. Do you have any idea how to sort it?

Comment: I'm going to do an fstab mount and work out why it's not working: [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591547/permanent-network-drive-mount-in-fstab-not-working)